# Is there a way to not change the size of a line when zooming in D3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, d3.js

I'm trying to remove the size update of my line when i zoom on my svg.

Basically my line is like that

```
points = [[this.x(first.longitude), this.y(0)], [this.x(first.longitude), this.y(first.altitude)]];
        this.line[i] = this.chart
        .append('path')
        .attr('d', curveafter(points))
        .attr('p', id.segmentName)
        .attr('stroke', "black")
        .attr('fill', 'none')
        .on('click', this.filter)
        .attr("stroke-width", 1)
```

and when i'm zooming, i'm updating the position of the line like that

```
updateChart(d) {
      var newX = d.transform.rescaleX(this.x);
      var newY = d.transform.rescaleY(this.y);

      this.xAxis.call(d3.axisBottom(newX))
      this.yAxis.call(d3.axisLeft(newY))

      this.line.forEach((line) => {
        line
        .attr("transform", d.transform)
        .attr("stroke-width", 1)
        }
      )
  },
```

But when i'm zooming, the size of my line increases, and when I zoom out it decreases.
How do I block the stroke-width (size) and not move it no matter what I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. Don't put your `<line>` under transformed `<g>`. When you handle a zoom event, recalculate the line endpoint coordinates and update the `<line>` attributes (**x1**,**y1**,**x2**,**y2**)
2. Set the line's `stroke-width` according to the zoom factor: `strokeWidth = 1 / e.transform.k` (I don't like this option but it can work)